# How to make Apache return 404 instead of 502

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404

I'm using Apache as a reverse proxy and when the origin servers return 502, I need Apache to return 404 instead. I saw a comment that said "output filter can intercept the 500 response and transform it into a 404" I could not figure this out, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should do that from framework, not from apache. The user should see 404, but you must see the errors in error logs.